# Docker "/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied" every pc (linux mint) reboot, it only goes away when uninstalling/installing docker again

Tags: linux, bash, docker, linux-mint

I use docker at work, and this happens every time with all images I have. Every time I reboot my notebook I have this same error, I also tried running with sudo but it doesn't change the error. But if I uninstall and reinstall, it works just fine, every single time (I'm reinstalling the exact same version).

My configs: I use Linux Mint 19.3, every uninstall and install I follow [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), and I after running the hello world image, I add my user to the group, following [this post install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). My /etc/apt/sources.list.d/addtional-repositories.list is only `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable`

My docker image is basically this one (I just changed some names to post here):

```
FROM postgres:11

COPY ./extensions/* /usr/local/bin/extensions/
COPY ./schemas/xpto/* /usr/local/bin/schemas/xpto/
COPY ./schemas/operation/* /usr/local/bin/schemas/operation/

COPY ./user_permissions/* /usr/local/bin/user_permissions/

COPY ./domains/* /usr/local/bin/domains/

COPY ./populate_domains/xpto/* /usr/local/bin/populate_domains/xpto/

COPY ./build.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 5432
```

I tried adding

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x ./build.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./build.sh"]
```

in the end of the docker file (instead of the last copy and before the expose) but it didn't help at all (the error changed to "/bin/bash: ./build.sh: Permission denied")

I just don't know what to do, I'm almost memorizing all the tutorials because every week I have to uninstall and reinstall docker at least 2 times, and I also can't find anyone that had the same problem. I really appreciate any help :)

EDIT:
To run I always use:

`docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 --name xpto-db -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust --net=host xpto-db-img`

Comment: At what point do you copy build.sh to /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Can we see the way you're running the image?  I.e. `docker run ...`

Comment: @sfb103 I just added in the question but here it is: `docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 --name xpto-db -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust --net=host xpto-db-img`

Comment: @Howard_Roark I don't think I need to copy it, as it has the commands to build the database, it doesn't have to be copied to the same folder. The image totally works, if the docker is uninstalled and installed again, the problem is just when I restart my computer :(

Comment: Can you try doing a `sudo service docker restart` and see if you have the same issue that you have when rebooting? I.e. when you reboot, you get the permission issue... When you just restart the docker service, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @sfb103 No, I don't... If it was working before, docker restart works too. I'll try it when I reboot.